# Image that doesn't show up in IE or Chrome only

Tags: image, internet-explorer, google-chrome, javax.imageio

I have a jpeg that shows up properly in FF, but won't appear in IE or Chrome. I tried downloading the image and loading it in IE and Chrome directly without success: both browsers shows a broken icon. So this is not a network issue.

This file is a result of an image resize by javax.imageio.ImageIO. I have processed over 1000 images successfully.

Windows explorer shows the thumbnail properly, and I can edit it successfully in Microsoft Office Picture Manager.

Is there any tool that could help me understand what is wrong with this file?

Comment: How about posting a link to the image.

Comment: I could do that, but then if somebody had the same issue it wouldn't help them. What I'm looking for is a tool that could pinpoint the problem with the file.

Comment: I see your point, but I doubt you will find that tool.  The combinations of errors and formats (and sub formats) are massive.

Comment: My problem was that the JPG had transparency... so I guess the image was really not a JPG, it just had a .JPG extension. After I noticed that, I just regenerated the image properly. (In PNG to not lose the transparency.) Seen as you are processing images with a tool, this was not likely your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is it's a CMYK JPG. Change it to RGB.

Comment: You were right. The file was ok, but it's CMYK JPG that is not handled well by java. See:
http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4799903

Comment: ...and even if Java had handled it correctly, IE can't display them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue several times (mostly in IE 6 and 7). 
Two things I've notice (except the colorspace CMYK / RGB, witch is the first thing to look for):

Even in Photoshop, when I changed the colorspace ("mode" in PS), and re-saved the image, often the change didn't seem to stick. So I often find it easier to do a copy/paste in a fresh new RGB 8 bit document.

Also, those images usually came from a Mac PS while I was working on a PC (or vice-versa) so something regarding RGB Mac/PC colorspace seems to be at stake here.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and thanks to twlichty for the correct answer to my issue. The file was a CMYK jpg format.

But I needed to keep it in CMYK as we are printing off the image as a looped background for office awards. As a solution I worked of the OP's final solution and I changed the image to PNG. I turned off Transparency as it was not needed and I unchecked Convert to sRGB to keep it in CMYK. This then created a CMYK image with a PNG wrapper that Internet Explorer was capable of printing. The final image colors look spot on as well.

Just wanted to leave my own issue and fix found related to this topic for others.

Cheers.

batty13

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is fix this one image and move on, I imagine you could fix it by simply writing it out with a different tool, perhaps after making a trivial change.

Comment: I tried to do a save-as in Microsoft Office Picture Manager, and the new images would not load.

Answer (score 0):

You need a library/class that supports CMYK, otherwise all you get is an error or, even worse, all you get is an unreadable pictures.
Look your documentation for references to "Colorspace".